# can t compile anything, no matter the body, this is the message i get

Tags: process, exit

class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
System.out.println("hello ntina");
}
```

}

MESSAGE
C:\Users\Jason.jdks\openjdk-14\bin\java.exe "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=52146:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Users\Jason\IdeaProjects\first try\out\production\first try" java.util.prefs.Base64
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
    at java.prefs/java.util.prefs.Base64.main(Base64.java:240)

Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

Can you please be more specific about your setup? It seems more of a Java/Intellij configuration issue than a programming question.